# pick random value from associated array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [JavaScript: Getting random value from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/javascript-getting-random-value-from-an-array)
>   [How can I choose an object key at random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428013/how-can-i-choose-an-object-key-at-random)

suppose we have an array like this:

```
var MrArray = new Array(5);
MrArray['one']='oneValue';
MrArray['two']='twoValue';
MrArray['three']='threeValue';
MrArray['four']='fourValue';
MrArray['five']='fiveValue';
```

ok?
the Array is associated.
and we have string key and string value.
now! how can i pick a random value from that?
**Edit:i want to use like this:**

```
<A href="Array value Here">Array Key Here</a>
```

Regards
Sam

Comment: You're very confused about arrays in JavaScript.  Arrays are always indexed and never associative.  However, Arrays are just special objects and objects allow you to define keys just like you are doing in your code.  See http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks all,But I Want to pick Key and Value in same  time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the method described [here](http://geomblog.blogspot.com/2008/01/happy-birthday-don-knuth.html) we can create the following function:

```
function randomKey(obj) {
    var ret;
    var c = 0;
    for (var key in obj)
        if (Math.random() < 1/++c)
           ret = key;
    return ret;
}
```

It returns a random key, so to get a random value from `MrArray`, do this:

```
var value = MrArray[randomKey(MrArray)];
```

[jsPerf benchmark](http://jsperf.com/random-object-key) comparing the speed of this and the other answer.

Comment: +1 for `1/++c`. I don't think I've seen that trick before.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
function fetch_random(obj) {
    var temp_key, keys = [];
    for(temp_key in obj) {
       if(obj.hasOwnProperty(temp_key)) {
           keys.push(temp_key);
       }
    }
    return obj[keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)]];
}
```

Src: [How can I choose an object key at random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428013/to-generate-items-in-associative-array-items-randomly)